# What is the difference between "point of view" and "perspective"?

Tags: differences

Until lately, my thought has been that *point of view* and *perspective* are the same. but doing grammar practice on the subjects, I find:

> **point of view** requires such explicit indications as "I, she, he, and so on"
> But
> **perspective** only requires the view of someone being indicated in an article.

So for example:

> If a question asks if the passage is narrated from the ***point of view*** of Henry Mulcahy, it can only be true if the word "I" is in the passage.
>
> **On** the other hand, if the question were to ask if the passage is an introduction of one character(A) through the ***perspective*** of another character(B). You only have to see if  passage presents (B) as (A) sees him, and if the narrator provides no independent or neutral information about (B).
> There is no need to look for any pronoun in order to determine the **perspective**.

Comment: You need to make clear whether you're talking about these terms as generally used, or as a part of the standard "jargon" used when discussing literary works.  "Point of view" has a specific meaning in literary jargon.

Answer (score 1):

No, *point of view* doesn't require an explicit indication of the subject. I would say that *point of view* and *perspective* are synonymous.

For instance, these are fine (and mean the same thing):

> *(no explicit subject)*
> Looking at the situation from a different **point of view**, ...
> Looking at the situation from a different **perspective**, ...
>
> *(explicit subject)*
> The novel is written from Ophelia's **point of view**, ...
> The novel is written from Ophelia's **perspective**, ...